# nextjs-13 : how to share data fetched in Layout with its pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am a newbie in NextJS.
To learn how it works I decided to use it on a project with Golang as a backend.

Actually, I am facing an issue related to layout.

Here are my routes:

```
- app
  - auth
  - orgs
    - [orgId]
      - members
      - transactions
      * layout.tsx (My issue is here)
      * page.tsx
    * page.tsx
  * page.tsx
  * layout.tsx
```

My issue is at the `app/orgs/[orgId]/layout.tsx` level. In that Layout, I fetch the organization information to fill some parts of the layout, mostly the header and the side navigation.

In the meantime, In all the subpages, I also need that information (the organization information). I mean in

- /orgs/[orgId]
- /orgs/[orgId]/members
- /orgs/[orgId/transactions

In the subpages, I am able to have access to the `[orgId]` parameters but I don't want to request the organization information every time because it is already available in the layout and I think it's possible to have access to it.

But how?

Do you know how to share the data fetched in the layout with its subpages?

Comment: Simply fetch it again. Duplicate requests via `fetch()` are deduped automatically.